# How to run Python3 project on Azure?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, python-3.x, azure

I'm trying to run my Python3 project on Azure. However, if I choose python version on Azure portal, getting script request (e.g. http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/static/app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js) receive 404 error.) Actually, it happens whenever I choose python version not only python 3.4 even though if I choose "off" as Python version, it runs correctly.

[Azure Portal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcyRY.png)

I created this project using "Django Web Project" in Visual Studio and deploy it from Command Line.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the steps done? How jquery script is related to the python3 project?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are using Visual Studio to manage your Django Web Project, I believe that you are using Virtual Environment. The Python Version you configure in the Azure Portal is for none-Virtual Environment. Setting this Version will change the path of static file requesting. That's why it returns 404.

If you want to change the python version for your app, you should change your Virtual Environment instead of setting the python version in the Azure Portal.

It's always a good practice to use Virtual Environment, so I don't suggest you to delete your Environment and use the default one. Here are the steps for adding a new Virtual Environment to your Django Project and switching between Environments.

1. Right click the **Python Environment** of you Project, and choose **Add Virtual Environment...**

   [image]
2. Select the python version you want for your project.

   [image]
3. Wait for your packages being installed.
4. Right click the **Python Environment** of you Project again, and choose **Add/Remove Python Environment...**
5. Select the Environment you want for your project, and unselect the others.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, you need to do two steps if you want to run Python3 for your Django webapp on Azure.

1. Choose the Python 3.4 version on Azure portal.
2. Make sure the `web.config` file at the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` is configured for Python3. You can access the Kudo Console via the url `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to check and edit the `web.config` file.

There are three configure file I marked red frame below. Please make sure  the `web.config` file as same as the `web.3.4.config` file.

[image]

Recommend that you can try to compare these config files to know the difference between Python3 and Python2, such as the content below.

For Python3 in the `web.3.4.config` file.

```
<add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Python34\python.exe|D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
```

For Python2 in the `web.2.7.config` file.

```
<add name="Python FastCGI" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Python27\python.exe|D:\Python27\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
```